# Reading data from MySQL to VB

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I'm just learning and working on a site using Asp.Net/VB/SQL.. I'm trying to read a full row of data from SQL to manipulate in my VB code. I so far have this..

```
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT  shopName
       ,shopLogo
       ,addressLine1
       ,city
       ,postcode
       ,phoneNumber
       ,pointsPerPound
       ,maxPoints
       ,info

FROM tblShopKeeper
WHERE orderID = @shopID
END
```

Which selects the data but how do I pass it back to VB ? 
I have this for the code..

```
Public Function SelectShop(ByVal orderString As Guid) As String
    Dim DBConnect As New DBConn
    Using db As DbConnection = DBConnect.Conn("DBConnectionString")
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = DBConnect.Command(db, "SelectShop")
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("shopID",         SqlDbType.uniqueIdentifier, ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = orderString

        db.Open()
        Dim shopName As String
        Dim shopLogo As String
        Dim addressLine1 As String
        Dim city As String
        Dim postcode As String
        Dim phoneNumber As String
        Dim pointsPerPound As Integer
        Dim maxPoints As Integer
        Dim info As String

        Dim DR As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

        While DR.Read
            shopName = DR("shopName")
            shopLogo = DR("shopLogo")
            addressLine1 = DR("addressLine1")
            city = DR("city")
            postcode = DR("postcode")
            phoneNumber = DR("phoneNumber")
            pointsPerPound = DR("pointsPerPound")
            maxPoints = DR("maxPoints")
            info = DR("info")
        End While

        DR.Close()
        DR = Nothing
        cmd.Dispose()
        cmd = Nothing
        db.Dispose()
        db.Close()

        Return shopName
    End Using
End Function
```

And I'm calling this simply with..
SelectShop(shopID)

The "Return" statement only allows me to pass one field back.. How do I pass all fields back to use in the code please ?

Be gentle.. I'm just a novice :-)
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class "Shop"

```
Public Class Shop

   public property ShopName as String
   public property ShopLogo as String
   public property addressLine1 as String
   ...
End Class
```

Change Function return type to Shop

```
Public Function SelectShop(ByVal orderString As Guid) As Shop
```

Update function code snippet as below:

```
 Dim DR As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

 Dim objShop as New Shop()

    While DR.Read
        objShop.ShopName = DR("shopName")
        objShop.ShopLogo = DR("shopLogo")
        ...    

    End While

... 'Your code

    Return shopName
```

Comment: Happy if that helps, please accept as answer if this is the case.

Comment: Many thanks, this has helps lots.. Almost there with it.. Just need to know how to declare it in the code now. Do I need to use RETURN still ? As a test, I tried doing RESPONSE.WRITE(OBJSHOP.POSTCODE) and it says objshop is not declared.

Comment: One option could be to create a new class file (Shop.vb) for Shop class. Then call the class in your existing function SelectShop. Yes still need to return Shop object.

Comment: Thanks again Sami. What would I put as the Return ? I tried Return shop but it didn't like it.